# Setup twiki admin user for edit page view and apache users for editable pages view

Tags: apache, authentication, installation, admin, twiki

I need some setup for twiki.

twiki is insatlled on linux and httpd basic authentication is enabled for the site.

By default the user logged in with apache authentication, is able to view edit option on each page. I want all users to view it as non-editable plain topics. I have registered one twiki account with admin user. I want to use this account for editing each topic.

Can you pls explain me on how to set this up?

best regards,
Srinivas.M

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit the templates to do this.

Look at `templates/viewtopicactionbuttons.tmpl` and find a line like this:

`%TMPL:DEF{"edit_or_create"}%%TMPL:P{context="new_topic" then="create_topic_link" else="edit_topic_link"}%%TMPL:END%`

You will need to change it to check if the user is logged in, only showing the button if they are. Try something like this (untested):

`%TMPL:DEF{"edit_or_create"}%%TMPL:P{context="authenticated" then="%TMPL:P{context="new_topic" then="create_topic_link" else="edit_topic_link"}%"}%TMPL:END%`